# Products of homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

I was wondering if there is a theorem like

"If $f_i:X_i\to Y_i$ are homeomorphisms then $\prod_i f_i : \prod_i X_i \to \prod_i Y_i$ is a homeomorphism"

for $I$ finite. What about $I = \mathbb N$? Also, what for the same theorem with diffeomorphism instead of homeomorphism? I think I can prove it for $I$ finite thinking of product like a disjoint union. This would also work for $I$ infinite?

Comment: In fact, it suffices to show: a) If each $f_i$ is continuous, then $\prod f_i$ is continuous. b) If each $f_i$ has an inverse then so does $\prod f_i$ and, moreover, $(\prod f_i)^{-1}=\prod f_i^{-1}$. (The second one is basically elementary set theory. For the first one, the [universal property of product topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Properties) might be useful.)

Comment: Now I found this older question: [If each component of a Cartesian product is homeomorphic to another space, are the Cartesian products homeomorphic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340897/if-each-component-of-a-cartesian-product-is-homeomorphic-to-another-space-are-t). It is almost the same as your question. (Perhaps they can be even considered duplicates.)